# For which starting points for $f(x) := \sqrt{1+x^2}$ does Newtons Method converge?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> For which starting points for $f(x) := \sqrt{1+x^2}$ does Newtons Method converge?

I recently learned about Newton's Method in class and the real theorem related to it that we did was that Newton's Method (under some regularity conditions) converges to a stationary point $x^*$ of $f \in \mathcal{C}^2$ if the starting point $x_0$ is sufficiently close to $x^*$.

However, I do not see how to apply this here. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: never. your function has no fixpoints.

Comment: Are you trying to use Newton's Method to minimize $f(x)$, as a toy example?

Comment: The theorem applies since $f$ is smooth but it doesn't exactly tell you what the largest possible interval around the minimum is. For that you have to get into the weeds of your specific problem, which here means writing down $g(x)=x-f'(x)/f''(x)$ and then analyzing how this function behaves on a neighborhood of zero. Specifically it will converge on a neighborhood of zero where $|g'|<1$ (though this is not in general optimal).

Comment: I recommend computing $N(x) = x-f(x)/f'(x)$ explicitly and then just trying it to see what happens.